# Extjs how to change tooltip on grid resize?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

Show tooltip to overflowed grid cell.

If the content of the cell do not fit in its visible part, I want to show tooltip with the full text of this cell and if its not don't show it. Any ideas how can I do it ?

```
// think about smth like this
// but don't know how to get content width

text: 'someHeaderName',
listeners: {
    resize( th, newWidth, height, oldWidth, oldHeight, eOpts ) {
        if (newWidth <= contentWidth) {
            this.showTooltip = true;
            th.up('panel').getView().refresh();
        }
    }
},
renderer: function(val, meta, rec, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
    if (this.showTooltip) {
        meta.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + val + '"';
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1dlj&view/editor check this out..

Comment: You mean on ellipsis part you want to show tip ?

Comment: @Jaydeep it was helpful for me, thanks.

Comment: @Tejas yes, thats what I want.

Comment: So did you get your answer from 1st comment or should I post ?

Comment: if u have different solution - post it of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
this.tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
    target: Ext.getBody(),
    delegate: '.x-grid-cell',
    trackMouse: true,
    listeners: {
        beforeshow: function(tip) {
            var cell = tip.triggerElement;
            var el = cell.children[0];

            if (el.offsetWidth >= el.scrollWidth || cell.getAttribute('data-qtip')) {
                return false;
            }

            tip.update(el.innerText);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your renderer function like this. Make sure `x-grid-cell-inner` is your grid inner cell class otherwise replace with your css class name. To refresh after every column resize use `getView().refresh()` function and remove otherlines from your resize listeners.

```
 listeners: {
  resize( th, newWidth, height, oldWidth, oldHeight, eOpts ) {
                th.up('panel').getView().refresh();
           }
 },
 renderer: function(val, meta, rec, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
    var colWidth = this.getColumns()[colIndex].width;
    var innercellclassEl = document.getElementsByClassName('x-grid-cell-inner ');
    var contentWidth = Ext.util.TextMetrics.measure(innercellclassEl,val).width;
    if ( colWidth < contentWidth) {
      meta.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + val + '"';
    }
    return val;
 }
```